# Odd narrow layout of Feed on Android

Tags: bug, android-app

This is a little odd, but the Android application's feed shows really narrow for items even on a wider screen.

Below is a picture of the layout on the screen of my Galaxy Tab E and how the narrowness is evil.  Note this only seems to be on the feed, and not specific site pages or questions/answers.

[image: Picture of Screen]

---

This has been marked as a duplicate to the one only showing a few items.  This is not the same issue.  ***It is not a duplicate.***

Comparatively, in the layout, you are able to still see more than two words on a line in the 'duplicate', but in this case on a tablet, I am less concerned with number of items on the feed but the width of the items actually displayed.

Compared to the iOS application, in which you can get about 50% more width on the *individiual* items in the feed so you can actually read them on the screen without opening them, this is very *very* hard to read when you only get two words in per line (or less) and have to scroll down just to read an entire title on the feed.

Comment: @qwer It is not a duplicate - i am not talking about # of items on the feed window, i'm talking about how on the Android app it is infinitely narrow, even compared to the layout screenshot you show in the 'possible duplicate'.  Number of items on the layout, not an issue.  The fact that the entire screen height in horiz. mode (and even more screen height in portrait mode) are consumed for a single item, with only one or two words max per line (in portrait mode, it's only about 6 chars. max per line).  Concerned about that, not the number of items on feed screen.

Comment: The duplicate shows the issue with *narrow width on feed* (or "overly-aggressive line wraps") whether it's on horizontal or vertical orientation, making it showing less. Whatever the result is, the cause is the same.

Comment: @qwer You're right, but that's only because the other screenshot didn't render on my screen that I said that.  This may actually be a duplicate (though I think StackExchange may not care since its' been left alone since April)